# numpy loglog linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, regression, loglog

What is the best way to find the linear regression of loglog data using numpy? When I plot the data and try

```
A = np.vstack([np.log10(X), np.ones(len(X))]).T
m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, np.log10(Y))[0]
ax.plot(X, [m*x + c for x in X], 'r')
```

where X and Y are the data lists, this is the result, obviously incorrect: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a linear regression on

```
log10(y) = m*log10(x) + c
```

then in (x,y) coordinates you have

```
y = (10**c) * x**m
```

That is, you have fit a power law to your data.  Change this

```
ax.plot(X, [m*x + c for x in X], 'r')
```

to

```
ax.plot(X, np.power(10, c) * np.power(X, m), 'r')
```